# Folder not showing on github, but is present in git

Tags: git, github

I have a project where a non-empty folder is displaying on my local file system, but is not present in github. It did not always used to be like this. I am not ignoring this folder. I know that git doesn't let you add empty folders. What could possibly be the problem? I tried re-adding it but its acting as if it were ignored. What can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: "I tried re-adding it" how? Git does not track directories. You need to track a file within the directory.

Comment: @larsmans "The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
packages/ST-Web/src/ST/Web/AWS/Config.hs
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added"

Comment: It's a lie tho, my .gitignore is not ignoring that file

Comment: @TheInternet git don't lies ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl see for yourself: http://lpaste.net/4174488287911608320

Comment: @TheInternet, try `git check-ignore packages/ST-Web/src/ST/Web/AWS/Config.hs` to see why it's being ignored.

Comment: "git check-ignore packages/ST-Web/src/ST/Web/AWS/Config.hs" gives
--> packages/ST-Web/src/ST/Web/AWS/Config.hs, which isn't present in my .gitignore and I have no nested .gitignores

Comment: You are sure that there are no more .gitignore files in the `packages/../...` path ?

Comment: @TheInternet, sorry, add the `--verbose` option.

Comment: @Chris, ahhhhh I have an executable generated named "web" that I ignore... and apparently the folder ST/Web/ gets entirely ignored because of that. Didn't know it was case-insensitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When trying to figure out why something is ignored, it is often useful to use the [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore.html) command:

```
$ git check-ignore --verbose some/file.txt
.gitignore:1:some   some/file.txt
```

The output can be interpreted like so:

> If `--verbose` is specified, the output is a series of lines of the form:
>
> ```
> <source> <COLON> <linenum> <COLON> <pattern> <HT> <pathname>
> ```
>
> `<pathname>` is the path of a file being queried, `<pattern>` is the
>   matching pattern, `<source>` is the pattern’s source file, and
>   `<linenum>` is the line number of the pattern within that source. If
>   the pattern contained a `!` prefix or `/` suffix, it will be preserved in
>   the output. `<source>` will be an absolute path when referring to the
>   file configured by `core.excludesfile`, or relative to the repository
>   root when referring to `.git/info/exclude` or a per-directory exclude
>   file.